# Dúvida com Listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quando digito este comando no console, ele me retorna uma lista vazia. Porém se eu criar um arquivo e mandar executar, não aparece nada, o que acontece? Como devo fazer?

```
lista = []

x = 1

while x > 0:
    x = int(input('digite um numero inteiro: '))
    lista.append(x)

print (lista)
```

Comment: Seu arquivo está na extensão .py? Tentou digitar sem o acento no "ú"?

Comment: Coloca seu código pra gente ver

Comment: Pessoal me desculpem, eu estava esquecendo um pequeno detalhe, colocar o print antes, vejam o código

Comment: Como exatamente você está criando o arquivo e mandando executar?

Answer (score 1):

No seu terminal `python3 nome_arquivo.py`

Answer (score 0):

para executar no terminal use `python nome_arquivo.py` lembrando que deve estar na mesma pasta em que o arquivo está. rodei seu script aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.